# Undefined state in child component using useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a [snake game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_(video_game_genre)) with React. Coordinates of the snake (`snakeDots` slice of state)are updated every second, and the new state should be reflected in the `Snake` component, which renders the snake to the screen. I am using `useReduce` so I can have synchronous update of State and I am Using useContext to spread the state to child to components. Upon first render I am getting error for state(`snakeDots`) undefined. Don't understand why since the state has initial values. Can anyone shed some light? thanks

In `App.js`:

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import Snake from "./Snake";
import Food from "./Food";

import { snakeContext } from "./contexts/snakeContext";

const getRandomCoordinates = () => {
  let min = 1;
  let max = 98;
  let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) / 2) * 2;
  let y = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) / 2) * 2;
  return [x, y];
};

function App() {
  const [snakeDots, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [
    [0, 0],
    [2, 0]
  ]);

  const [food, setFood] = useState(getRandomCoordinates());

  const [direction, setDirection] = useState("RIGHT");

  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(200);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => dispatch({ type: direction }), speed);
    document.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
  }, []);

  function onKeyDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 38:
        setDirection("UP");
        break;
      case 40:
        setDirection("DOWN");
        break;
      case 37:
        setDirection("LEFT");
        break;
      case 39:
        setDirection("RIGHT");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("wrong key");
    }
  }

  function reducer(snakeDots, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "RIGHT":
        let head = snakeDots[snakeDots.length - 1];
        head = [head[0] + 2, head[1]];
        snakeDots.push(head);
        snakeDots.shift();
        return snakeDots;
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="game-area">
      <snakeContext.Provider value={{ snakeDots, food }} />
        <Snake />
        <Food dot={food} />
      <snakeContext.Provider />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in `Snake.jsx`:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { snakeContext } from "./contexts/snakeContext";

export default function Snake () {
  debugger
  const { snakeDots } = useContext(snakeContext);
  debugger;
  return (
    <div>
      {snakeDots.map((dot, i) => {
        const style = {
          left: `${dot[0]}%`,
          top: `${dot[1]}%`
        };
        return <div className="snake-dot" key={i} style={style}></div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

in `snakeContext.js`:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export const snakeContext = createContext();
```

**Edit:**

The error message is:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'snakeDots' of undefined` in `Snake.js`, the component doesn't even render, line 5.

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error, and what line is throwing that error?

Comment: thanks @AlexWayne, just added error message in the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your issue. You are closing the first provider and not wrapping the snake component, but rather creating TWO providers with no children. Change the return in App.js to:

```
  return (
    <div className="game-area">
      <snakeContext.Provider value={{ snakeDots, food }}>
        <Snake />
        <Food dot={food} />
      </snakeContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
```

**What you currently have (fixed indentation to see the mistake)**

```
  return (
    <div className="game-area">
      {/* First provider */}
      <snakeContext.Provider value={{ snakeDots, food }} />

      <Snake />

      <Food dot={food} />

      {/* Second provider */}
      <snakeContext.Provider />
    </div>
  );
```

Snake is not a child of any Provider, but a sibling.